# Trying to run junit test and get the following error: unreported exception Overflow; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, junit

I'm not supposed to touch the code, simply run junit tests on it.

I get the error whenever I run the insert method. I tested isFull (with assertFalse), so the exception shouldn't be thrown?

I get the error: unreported exception Overflow; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
public void insert( int x ) throws Overflow
{
    if( isFull( ) )
        throw new Overflow( );

    // Percolate up
    int hole = ++currentSize;
    for( ; hole > 1 && x< array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2 )
        array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
    array[ hole ] = x;
}

@Test
public void testBinaryHeapDefault() {
    BinaryHeap bh1 = new BinaryHeap( 5 );
    assertEquals(false, bh1.isFull( ));
    bh1.insert( 2 );
}
```

Comment: "*I tested isFull (is false), so the exception shouldn't be thrown?*" - Exactly. The test fails because the expected behaviour is not, that this exception is thrown. But we cannot say more since method declaration of `isFull()` is missing. Please add a [MCVE].

Comment: Just to clarify the test( assertEquals(false, bh1.isFull( ));) passes, I get the error whenever I try to run insert. 

'    /**
     * Test if the priority queue is logically full.
     * @return true if full, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isFull( )
    {
        return currentSize == array.length - 1;
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code. The code in the comment is unreadable. The method `isFull()` is called in both tests.

Comment: @Turing85, sorry I moved it to the top in the original question.

Comment: Still no [MCVE]. Where is `currentSize` defined? Where is `array` defined?

Comment: @Turing85, sorry moved them to the top now.

Comment: your code ist pretty much unreadable. What belongs where? What in which class?

Comment: @Turing85 everything is in one class, if you scroll down there's about 5 new lines followed by public class BinaryHeap, that is the entire class exactly c/p'ed.

Comment: No your code makes sense. What you get is not a runtime error, but a compilation error. Method `testBinaryHeapDefault()` coult throw an `Overlfow`. `Overflow` seems to be a checked exception and must be either catched or rethrown.

Comment: @Turing85, sorry to clarify my test class could throw an exception so I need to write something like this within the test itself?

`boolean wasThrown = false;
        try {
            bh1.insert( 10 );
        } catch(Overflow) {wasThrown = true;}
        
        assertFalse(wasThrown);`

This throws an error but it simply says "expected"

Comment: No. You only need to declare that the test method might throw an `Exception`: `public void testBinaryHeapDefault() throws Overflow { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say on comment in your question

> I get the error: unreported exception Overflow; must be caught or declared to be thrown

The Java Language Spec requires that any Exception declared should be catch OR throw by a `try-catch` block OR declared in method name using the clause throws [Exception].

In your case, you can try one these:

1. Adding clause `throws Overflow` on the end of the method `public void testBinaryHeapDefault()`
2. Adding a `try-catch` block inside `public void testBinaryHeapDefault()`

Using the first approach,

```
@Test
public void testBinaryHeapDefault() throws Overflow{
      BinaryHeap bh1 = new BinaryHeap( 5 );
      assertEquals(false, bh1.isFull( ));
      bh1.insert( 2 );
}
```

Notice that Overflow is not a Exception used by Java Core, so you need to put it inside your project. See some typical Exceptions [List of Java Exceptions - JDK8](https://programming.guide/java/list-of-java-exceptions.html)